# Swift AVFoundation stitching multiple videos together and keep preferred transform

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

I'm trying to stitch multiple video clips together. If I stitch each AVAsset in one AVMutableCompositionTrack it works but loses the transformation on the first asset by appending another one with enabled mirroring mode for front facing camera. Can I somehow use multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack of type video in one AVMutableComposition?

```
        // create mix composition
        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        // insert video track
        let videoCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

        // keep track of total duration
        var totalDuration = kCMTimeZero

        // for each video clip add to mutable composition and transform each video layer
        for (index, videoClip) in videoClips.enumerated() {

            if let videoAsset = videoClip.asset, let videoAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first {

                // insert current video track to composition
                try videoCompositionTrack!.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAssetTrack, at: totalDuration)
                videoCompositionTrack?.preferredTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform

                // shift duration to next
                totalDuration = CMTimeAdd(totalDuration, videoAsset.duration)
            }
        }

        // Use AVAssetExportSession to export video
        let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080)
        assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4

        // get needed save url to save the video to recommended url
        let movieDestinationUrl = self.getRecommendedSaveUrl()

        // seting up asset export session
        assetExport?.outputURL = movieDestinationUrl
        assetExport?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        // export video to file system asyc
        assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            assetExport?.cancelExport()
            switch assetExport!.status {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                break
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                break
            default:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion?(movieDestinationUrl, nil)
                }
            }
            if ((assetExport?.error) != nil) {
                AppDelegate.logger.error("Could not create user video: \((assetExport?.error)!)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion?(nil, assetExport?.error)
                }
            }
        })
```

I'm trying to use something like this and multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack's with different CGAffineTransform objects.

```
        // create mix composition
        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        // keep track of total duration
        var totalDuration = kCMTimeZero

        // for each video clip add to mutable composition and transform each video layer
        for (index, videoClip) in videoClips.enumerated() {

            if let videoAsset = videoClip.asset, let videoAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first {

                // insert video track
                let videoCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(index))

                // insert current video track to composition
                try videoCompositionTrack!.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAssetTrack, at: totalDuration)
                videoCompositionTrack?.preferredTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform

                // shift duration to next
                totalDuration = CMTimeAdd(totalDuration, videoAsset.duration)
            }
        }

        // Use AVAssetExportSession to export video
        let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080)
        assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4

        // get needed save url to save the video to recommended url
        let movieDestinationUrl = self.getRecommendedSaveUrl()

        // seting up asset export session
        assetExport?.outputURL = movieDestinationUrl
        assetExport?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        // export video to file system asyc
        assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            assetExport?.cancelExport()
            switch assetExport!.status {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                break
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                break
            default:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion?(movieDestinationUrl, nil)
                }
            }
            if ((assetExport?.error) != nil) {
                AppDelegate.logger.error("Could not create user video: \((assetExport?.error)!)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion?(nil, assetExport?.error)
                }
            }
        })
```

In the case above I'm not able to get any useable video: it is much shorter than it should be. I'm trying to avoid using any AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction because it takes too long to process but it would still be an option if it worked for any resolution and especially with mirroring support.

```
        // create mix composition
        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        // keep track of total duration
        var totalDuration = kCMTimeZero

        // keeps all layer transformations for each video asset
        var videoCompositionLayerInstructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]()

        // for each video clip add to mutable composition and transform each video layer
        for (index, videoClip) in videoClips.enumerated() {

            if let videoAsset = videoClip.asset {

                // use first video asset track for setting like height and width
                let videoAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first!

                // insert video trakc
                let videoCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(index))

                // insert current video track to composition
                try videoCompositionTrack!.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(totalDuration, videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: videoAssetTrack, at: totalDuration)
                videoCompositionTrack?.preferredTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform

                let videoCompositionLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoAssetTrack)
                videoCompositionLayerInstruction.setTransform((videoCompositionTrack?.preferredTransform)!, at: totalDuration)
                videoCompositionLayerInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: videoAsset.duration)

                // apply instruction
                videoCompositionLayerInstructions.append(videoCompositionLayerInstruction)

                // shift duration to next
                totalDuration = CMTimeAdd(totalDuration, videoAsset.duration)
            }
        }

        let videoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, totalDuration)
        videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = videoCompositionLayerInstructions

        let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1080, height: 1920)
        mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        mainComposition.instructions = [videoCompositionInstruction]

        // Use AVAssetExportSession to export video
        let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080)
        assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4

        // get needed save url to save the video to recommended url
        let movieDestinationUrl = self.getRecommendedSaveUrl()

        // seting up asset export session
        assetExport?.outputURL = movieDestinationUrl
        assetExport?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        assetExport?.videoComposition = mainComposition
```

Anybody an idea how to implement this functionality?

- Note: I don't need to care about audio at all.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?